# Exclude jquery ui style from certain buttons/inputs

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, button, input

I need to exclude certain elements from being styled by jquery ui. Is it possible to exclude a certain section of code or disable jquery ui for a specific input button or anything similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think JQuery UI does much unless you actually add their css classes to elements yourself (I could be wrong though). If you're using plugins that use JQuery UI styling and want to undo it, I don't think there's anything you can do short of writing a javascript function to traverse a section of DOM and strip all the jquery UI classes.

Comment: you were correct... I had a $(button piece of code in my footer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should be easily accomplished by clever CSS selectors.  Instead of calling jquery-ui on all elements, or on all of one class, use different classes on the particular ones you want to behave differently.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[type=button]").hide();
```

Use these

http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Comment: I want to disable the css from applying to that particular button, not hide the button entirely.